# Straightforward InnerHTML Replacement For Chrome?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, innerhtml

I'm trying to write a function to log my stock trades after they're finished. Basically it's pulling values from different text boxes on the page and lumping them together as a variable to store in an array with other variables of the same type. The contents of the array should be visible in a "session" section at the bottom of the page. It doesn't need to save to file or do anything fancy, it just needs to keep those values there while I work.

I've done this before for work, but I prefer Chrome as my browser now and it doesn't support the innerHTML property. I would just use this:

document.getElementById("session").innerHTML=history

But I can't. Googling the problem I can't seem to get a straight answer, the results are all about consoles and whatnot. There's some mention of document.write but I think that would just wipe out the page, and that's not what I want at all. There's gotta be a simple way for Chrome to just view what's in the array.

Any ideas? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What does "But I can't" mean here? I just tried typing this in the console of Chrome and it seemed to work just fine.

Comment: If I run the function in IE it displays the word "Test" from the array. When I run it in Chrome nothing happens.

Comment: I just tried it in the Chrome console. And it worked just fine. Your question could be a lot better. Aside from not saying what didn't work, you should really post your actual code.

Comment: Chrome definitely supports `innerHTML`. However, `history` is a native object in `window`, and the name seems to be protected in the global scope in Chrome. If your `history` variable is defined at global scope, the only result you'd get would be  `[object Object]`. As Jonathan has stated above, we need more code to solve the problem.

Comment: I just copied the function into its own page and it actually does work there. Interesting. I'll monkey with it again when I get home and post the code.

Comment: Thanks Teemu, it turned out to be a combination of name issues. It didn't like "history" as an object name, but apparently it also didn't like the function name which was "evaluate". It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

That does too work in chrome.

```js
document.getElementById('myUniqueButtonId').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('myUniqueId').innerHTML = '<b>text was changed</b>';
  };
```

```html
<p id="myUniqueId">
  
  text
  
  </p>

<input id="myUniqueButtonId" type="button" value="replace using innerHTML" />
```

Comment: That's strange. I don't see anything very different about your code, but it most definitely doesn't work for me. If I run the function I posted while in Chrome, nothing at all happens. If I run it in IE it posts the word "Test" which is what's in the array at present.

Comment: If you can recreate the problem with a snippet of code in your question, we will be able to help you.  Without seeing the exact code you are using, we can't help.